# how SeekableByteChannel is working?

Tags: java

As
[SeekableByteChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html) is an interface,how are we invoking its methods from Files class's [newByteChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel) method.

I Know how to invoke it .But i cant understand the concept because an interface doesn't implements the behavior

1 more Question.I have seen many times in java example code that interface methods are invoked or called.But as far as i know interface doesn't initialize or implements the methods.

```
SeekableByteChannel idd =  Files.newByteChannel(file);
idd.size();
```

How does the above code works because SeekableByteChannel is an interface and Files class doesn't implement the methods of SeekableByteChannel .So where SeekableByteChannels methods are initialized.

Please Help

Comment: "an interface doesn't implements the behavior" <-- of course not, but an interface is a contract which implementations must obey. So, what is the real question here? Is it that you don't understand the contract of `SeekableByteChannel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `interface` in Java is nothing more but a contract; at the compiler level, the only contract is that if you `implements` an interface, you must have an implementation of all methods (for classes which are not `abstract`):

```
public interface Foo
{
    /*
     * Any invocation of this method sends the instance to the moon
     */
    void foo();
}
```

If you have a concrete class which you can instantiate and which implements `Foo`, such as:

```
public class MyClass
    implements Foo
{
    // must implement foo()
    @Override
    public void foo() { stayOnEarth(); }
}
```

then you can do:

```
final Foo foo = new MyClass();
```

As you have a reference to an instance of type `Foo`, it means you can invoke `foo()` on it:

```
foo.foo();
```

The JVM will look up method `foo()` and find it.

Now: **the fact that you have implemented `foo()` is one thing; the fact that you obey the contract of this interface is another. The compiler does not give a <beep> if you stay on Earth or go right to Antares: it cannot enforce that**.

This is a question of trust first and foremost: if you implement an interface, you are expected to understand what this interface means; which is why there is documentation. The compiler cannot help any further but to enforce that you *at least* implement the needed methods.

Comment: SeekableByteChannel idd =  Files.newByteChannel(file);
    idd.size();                                                                        can you explain me the above code@fge

Comment: What don't you understand with it?

Comment: The SeekableByteChannel is an interface .It means that the methods are not intialized in the SeekableByteChannel,and even the Files class doesn't implement the seekableByteChannel methods.So from where SeekableByteChannel method 'size()' is initialized.@fge

Comment: It doesn't matter. At runtime, the JVM will look up the method in the object instance. The fact that you access it via an interface is secondary. It is just like when you do `List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: `Files.newByteChannel()` is a static factory method: it instantiates an object which _implements_ SerializableByteChannel.

Comment: Thanks i got it.you have made a mistake,please change SerializableByteChannel to SeekableByteChannel.@fge

Answer (score 0):

It seems your underlying question is how do interfaces work. The common buzzword that goes with interfaces is "contract". If your class implements an interface, it implements this contract. The contract means that the class MUST define the functions declared in the interface. Thus if we have -

```
Interface InterfaceTest{
    void foo();
}

Class Implementer implements InterfaceTest{
```

the class Implementer MUST implement the function foo() or there will be a compiler error -

```
void foo(){
    //Do stuff.
}
```

Note that `Files` does *not* implement `SeekableByteChannel`. So  `Files` does *not* have any relation to it. Thus `Files` can have any functions it wants, including ones in `SeekableByteChannel` without issue.

Comment: It might also be good to mention polymorphism at this point. Even though `test` doesn't give an implementation of foo(), some class, somewhere, does. All we know about it is that it implements `test`, and so we can call foo().

Comment: I know what you are explaining.But it didn't answer my question@Dgrin91